# Drag and drop menuitems

Tags: javascript, firefox, drag-and-drop, firefox-addon, xul

I want to rearrange menuitems by drag and drop in my firefox addon like the bookmarks in the Bookmarks menu. Specifically, I want the blue insertion marker to appear while dragging a menuitem over valid places. Can someone show me how to do this or tell me where the relevant code for bookmarks is located?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI [draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) are the two plugins I would use to achieve this effect. As for the insertion marker, I would investigate modifying the `div` (or container) element that was about to have content dropped into it. It should be possible to modify the border in some way or add a JavaScript/jQuery listener that listens for the hover (element about to be dropped) event and modifies the border or adds an image of the insertion marker in the right place.